# HTTPS (SSL) Request Reading Cert From Keystore Without a Library

Tags: java, ssl, https, jks

I'm looking for some sample code that would read from the JKS and issue an HTTPS request with SSL and it doesn't use a third party library.  I've only seen samples using libraries such as Axis.j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an HTTPS URL, with an `HttpsURLConnection` or even `HttpURLConnection`. Java will do the rest. No 3rd-party libraries required.

If you need to use a custom truststore, set the system property [`javax.net.ssl.trustStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores).

Similarly, if you need to use a keystore, i.e. if the server is requesting client authentication, set the system properties `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`.